# fill XML file with special content

Tags: java, xml, transformation

I am working on a project in which I need to fill some xml file with a special content, for example let's say I have an `example.xml` file :

```
<A>
    <B>testB</B>
    <C>
        <D>testD</D>
        <E>
            <F>testF</F>
        </E>
    </C>
</A>
<G>testG</G>
```

expected output is :

```
<A>
    <B>{{ A.B }}</B>
    <C>
        <D>{{ A.C.D }}</D>
        <E>
            <F>{{ A.C.E.F }}</F>
        </E>
    </C>
</A>
<G>{{ G }}</G>
```

how to solve this problem?

Comment: You probably want [DocumentBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newDocumentBuilder()).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here are many java libs that can do this thing, please refer to this:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-xml

From your example, seems you want to replace the text with the [xPath of the DOM element], so you need to do those steps:

1. Iterate the DOM and find the element which has text
2. Get the XPath of this element
3. Replace the text with the Xpath you get in step 2